# Using stateful web services with Mathematica 9

Tags: version-9, webservices

The [WebServices](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/WebServices/tutorial/Overview.html) package in *Mathematica* 9 no longer seems to support [stateful](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13734/stateful.htm) web sessions. This requires the client (i.e., the WebServices package) to pass back the HTTP Cookies that it receives from the web service. With *Mathematica* 8 this worked without problems. In *Mathematica* 9 this is no longer the case. Each request looks like a newly established session on the web service server side.

Is there a way to re-enable support for stateful web services in *Mathematica* 9?

Comment: Could you give a short example of a call that worked in 8 and doesn't in 9?